How to Set a RewriteRule Based on RewriteMap Lookup in Apache?
I’m trying to create a rewrite rule in Apache to match URLs not matching a specific value retrieved from a RewriteMap.
I have a RewriteMap defined as follows:
RewriteMap product_map txt:/path/to/product_map.txt

The RewriteMap contains entries like this:
55-55f /tv-backlight/55-55f
65-65ju /tv-backlight/65-65ju

My goal is to:

Extract a product key from the URL (e.g., 55-55f).
Lookup the product key in the RewriteMap to get the corresponding primary URL.
Compare the current REQUEST_URI with the retrieved primary URL from the RewriteMap.
Apply a 410 Gone status for any URL that does not match the primary URL.

What I Tried:
Attempt 1: Using Basic RewriteCond
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond ${product_map:%1|NOT_FOUND} !=NOT_FOUND
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=${product_map:%1|NOT_FOUND}

RewriteRule ^ - [G,L]


Expected: It should extract the product key, retrieve the primary URL, and compare the two.
Result: It fails because ${product_map:%1|NOT_FOUND} on the right-hand side of RewriteCond is not evaluated. Apache treats ${product_map:%1|NOT_FOUND} as a literal string.

Attempt 2: Using RewriteCond expr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond ${product:%1|NOT_FOUND} ^(.*)$

RewriteCond expr "%{REQUEST_URI} != %2"
RewriteRule ^ - [G,L]


Expected: It should extract the product key, retrieve the primary URL, and compare the two.
Result: It fails because %2 on the right-hand side of RewriteCond is not evaluated. Apache treats %2 as a literal string.

